# Handling a get request with a response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

So as the title suggests, to handle a get request, you create a doGet method and pass in a http servlet request and response.

Now an example code snippet I am looking at below is confusing me.
This is:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Yahoo!!!!!!!!</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("My First Servlet");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");

}
```

The line which confuses me is:

```
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

Is this assigning the output to the response object? The assignment to me reads: "assign whatever is in response.getWriter to PrintWriter 'out'" and not the other way round, so how on earth is the output being returned as a response? is it being handled automatically beneath the curtains or am I missing something blindly obvious?

Thank you

Comment: With every connection to websever, you have output stream associated with response. So its when client creates connection client associates the writer with socket and that's what you get from `getWriter` method.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `spring`. The code you have above is for a servlet

Comment: My apologies, I was following this in a spring tutorial, I'll remove the tag if possible

Comment: You have assigned reference to a Writer object in out variable and Writer is the object which is connected to the client, so when you write something to the writer it actually sending that to the output stream of client. IMHO take a good book and read about object references this doesn't seem right time to go for web applications until comfortable with core java

Comment: Nothing too complicated. response is a HttpServletResonse object and calling getWriter() method on it allow you to write text to be sent to the client. See the doc here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a servlet the response data can be sent as text or in binary form.

For character data (text) `PrintWriter` is used whose object can be obtained from [getWriter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter())

For binary data  use ServletOutputStream. ServletOutputStream can be obtained from [getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()).

Answer (score 0):

Adding some information to Response object may not be necessary done with assignment. When you change Response object with some **set** method - that's the same assignment. Right? So in your example you just writing some information to Response's object **Writer** parameter with *println* method which play a role of assignment.